Server error when attempting to clear a question's migration history
Noticed earlier on Stack Overflow and confirmed to be network-wide by Spevacus.
When selecting the Mod -> Clear Migration history button on a post that's been migrated elsewhere, you get an unhelpful error message on submit.

Under the hood, it looks like the page is throwing a 302 that redirects to the /error URL.
https://stackoverflow.com/admin/posts/<post ID here>/remove-migration-history


Fast-tracked status-review on this because we science'd together. Tested it on this post.

Related Mod Teams post (mod-only link)
